# Libreoffice Solver to java implementation with apache-commons-math

Tags: java, apache-commons-math, simplex-algorithm

Trying to implement and solve a Linear Programming problem with in Java using apache-commons-math:

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
       </dependency>
```

Here is the code:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.PointValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.*;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.GoalType;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void simplex() {

        double[] supplierCapacities = {200, 100, 50}; // cells G8:G10
        double[] consummerCapacities = {150, 75, 50, Arrays.stream(supplierCapacities).sum()}; // cells B12:E12
        int numberOfSuppliers = supplierCapacities.length;
        int numberOfConsummers = consummerCapacities.length;

        double[] prices = {
                2, 2, 2, 1,
                2, 2, 2, 1,
                2, 2, 2, 1
        }; // cells B16:E18
        LinearObjectiveFunction objectiveFunction = new LinearObjectiveFunction(prices, 0); // cell C4 to maximize

        // constraints
        List<LinearConstraint> constraintsList = new ArrayList<>();

        // the amount of products from supplier N to any consumers must not exceed the supplier capacity
        // F8:F10 <= G8:G10
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSuppliers; ++i) {
            double[] coeffs = new double[numberOfConsummers];
            Arrays.fill(coeffs, 1.0);
            LinearConstraint lessOrEqualToSupplierCapacity = new LinearConstraint(coeffs, Relationship.LEQ, supplierCapacities[i]);
            constraintsList.add(lessOrEqualToSupplierCapacity);
        }
        // the amount of products received by consummer M from any supplier must not exceed the consommer capacity
        // B11:E11 <= B12:E12
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfConsummers; ++i) {
            double[] coeffs = new double[numberOfSuppliers];
            Arrays.fill(coeffs, 1);
            LinearConstraint lessOrEqualtToConsommerCapacity = new LinearConstraint(coeffs, Relationship.LEQ, consummerCapacities[i]);
            constraintsList.add(lessOrEqualtToConsommerCapacity);
        }
        // gather up all constraints
        LinearConstraintSet linearConstraintSet = new LinearConstraintSet(constraintsList);

        // solve
        SimplexSolver solver = new SimplexSolver();
        PointValuePair solution = solver.optimize(objectiveFunction, linearConstraintSet, GoalType.MAXIMIZE, new NonNegativeConstraint(true));

        System.out.println(solution);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        simplex();
    }
}
```

The code throws an `UnboundedSolutionException`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.UnboundedSolutionException: solution non bornée
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.SimplexSolver.doIteration(SimplexSolver.java:325)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.SimplexSolver.doOptimize(SimplexSolver.java:389)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.SimplexSolver.doOptimize(SimplexSolver.java:65)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.BaseOptimizer.optimize(BaseOptimizer.java:153)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.BaseMultivariateOptimizer.optimize(BaseMultivariateOptimizer.java:65)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.MultivariateOptimizer.optimize(MultivariateOptimizer.java:63)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.LinearOptimizer.optimize(LinearOptimizer.java:94)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.optim.linear.SimplexSolver.optimize(SimplexSolver.java:154)
    at Main.simplex(Main.java:53)
    at Main.main(Main.java:59)
```

However I doubt this problem is unbounded. Using Libreoffice Solver, it appears to be working. Here is a screenshot of the spreadsheet, the comments in the java code refers to this spreadsheet.

[image]

The problem is to find the quantity to deliver from suppliers to consumers maximizing the profits given prices for each pair or (supplier,consummer) (min-cost max-flow)

Comment: What is the question? You didn't share the error.

Comment: The problem was at the very end. Edited to make it obvious from the beginning: UnboundedSolutionException while the same problem with the same data is resolved using Libreoffice Solver so I guess my code is not properly creating the constraints or initializing the data.

Comment: Please provide the [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) including the stacktrace. Also add the details for reproduction like imports, main(), etc. for a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).